# Bash script globing error when doing a curl for custom Github CLI API with oAuth token header

Tags: git, bash, api, shell, oauth

I have this bash script that I wrote that allows me to open a new git repo from terminal so I don't have to visit the site at all.

I was stuck for hours last night trying to send the oAuth params in the curl header like this: `curl -H "Authorization: token FOO-TOKEN-HERE" https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"my-new-repo-name"}'`

The token string is stored in a file and assigned to a variable with a `grep` function called like `$(secret NAME-OF-SECRET-VARIABLE)`.

I tried escaping double quotes, but still kept getting errors from Github.

Then I printed out then final url that Github was getting sent, and it was 100% correct format(on my end). I copied the url and just pasted in in terminal and it worked. But wont work from shell script.

This is the script.

```
 createNewRepo() {

  local gitUserName gitAuthToken gitNewRepoName gitOriginUrl token

  gitUserName=$(git config --get user.name)
  gitPassword=$(secret gitPassword)
  gitAuthToken=$(secret githubApiAuthToken)
  gitNewRepoName=$(echo "$@" | sed 's/ /-/g')
  token=$(secret githubApiPlainAuthToken)
  gitOriginUrl=git@github.com:$gitUserName/$gitNewRepoName.git

  apiUrlBuilder $gitUserName $gitAuthToken $gitNewRepoName $gitOriginUrl $token
}

apiUrlBuilder() {

  local statusCode date

  gitRepoUrl="https://api.github.com/repos/$gitUserName/$gitNewRepoName"
  repo="{\"name\":\"$gitNewRepoName\"}"
  api="-g -u $gitUserName:$gitPassword -X POST https://api.github.com/user/repos -d $repo"

  curl $api
}
```

As you can see. I switched to using the -u option and that works. But I want to use the Oauth token in the header.

The error I kept getting was along the lines of this. Just the column number changed once. 
`[globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 1`

This is one of the ways I tried for creating the url.

```
repo="{\"name\":\"$gitNewRepoName\"}"
api="-H $githubAuthToken https://api.github.com/user/repos -d $repo"
```

For the repo variable. I tried encapsulating the --data (aka "`repo`" variable) in single quotes and double.

Neither worked.

Any help would be great! Thank-you.

Comment: Don't stuff arguments into a string. Use an array. Try: `api=(-g -u "$gitUserName:$gitPassword" -X POST https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "$repo")` and `repo='{"name":"'"$gitNewRepoName"'"}'` and `curl "${api[@]}"`. You may also need to url-encode `repo` before sending it.

Comment: @EtanReisner, you often provide answers in comments. Cut it out! ;)

Comment: @glennjackman Heh. I suffer from an advanced case of "wanting to be sure" syndrome. =)

Comment: @EtanReisner I really appreciate it. But it still seems to be throwing a fit if I want to use the oAuth token in header.

This is the string:
`"Authorization: token b1334e52cfda69d2c6f61073d7d987276af355c6"`

Comment: You pass arguments (unquoted!) to `apiUrlBuilder` but don't actually use them anywhere. Does the value of `$githubAuthToken` have the quotes in it? It shouldn't. The use of the variable should though. Also define "throwing a fit"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not stuff arguments into a string. You should use an array instead. It is often impossible to get quoting right when using a string.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 for details about this topic.

So, in this case, you should try something like this instead:

```
repo='{"name":"'"$gitNewRepoName"'"}'
api=(-g -u "$gitUserName:$gitPassword" -X POST https://api.github.com/user/repos -d "$repo")

curl "${api[@]}"
```

You might also need to url-encode the contents of `$repo` before you can send them but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you see the comment I left on your original comment. I just noticed. When I try to pass the the oAuth token in place of using username and password. this is the error.

$ git new test
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "Authorization
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: token
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 34b34b5345bl3b5jh34FOONUMBER"
{
  "message": "Requires authentication",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3"
}
error! 404

Comment: @JaredLCowan Yeah, that's word-splitting on the host value. That's curl seeing `-H Authorization: token xxxxx` as individual words. Try using `api=(-H "$githubAuthToken" ...)`.

Comment: Sir Etan, you're the freakin' man! That worked. I removed the double quotes from the oAuth header variable and used the rest of your code and it worked. I owe you.